# Documenting abstract factory method return types in PHP with docblocks

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, abstract-factory

This has been asked again and again, but the replies are a bit old and I'm somewhat desperately hoping something changed since "can't be done" replies.

Context:

```php
    class AbstractBuildObject {}
    class Hammer extends AbstractBuildObject{}
    class Nail extends AbstractBuildObject{}

    class AbstractFactory{    
        /**
          * return $type
          */
        public function build1(string $type): AbstractBuiltObject {
            return new $type();
        }

        /**
          * return any(AbstractBuiltObject)
          */
        public function build2(string $someArg): AbstractBuiltObject {
            $type = $this->decideTypeBasedOnArgsAndState($someArg);
            return new $type();
        }
    }
```

I tried to represent what I need with the annotations above the builders.

`return $type` (or ideally `return $type of AbstractBuiltObject` should hint that the return type is specified in the input parameter.

In the second case, `any(AbstractBuiltObject)` signifies that any derived concretion of the abstract class  might be returned.

So I need some kind of annotation to achieve the effects I described. These annotations obviously don't work, I just used them for illustrating the concept.

I know one might be tempted to use pipe type joins like `return Hammer|Nail`, but in my case, the factory class should hold be modified every time a new concrete implementation is added to the project, it's also not specific enough in the `build1` case, where I know precisely what the return type should be.

So, in short, I need this to work at least in PhpStorm:

```php
    (new AbstractFactory())->build1(Hammer::class)-> // I should have Hammer autocomplete here
    (new AbstractFactory())->build2('foo')-> // I should have autocomplete of any concretion of the abstract here
```

Comment: How is `any(AbstractBuiltObject)` supposed to differ from just `AbstractBuiltObject`? Also note, what you're describing is essentially what interfaces are for. Make your concretions implement an interface and then typehint the interface.

Comment: @AlexHowansky `any(AbstractBuiltObject)` should be a static-analyser equivalent of the hardtyped `Hammer|Nail`. That is, I should get an autocomplete and further type iferrence for any i.e. method that is implemented on `Hammer` but not on the abstract.

Comment: PhpStorm has **Advanced Metadata** functionality for that. It is used by things like [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), Symfony plugin etc etc -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html

Comment: Otherwise look at the PHPStan / Psalm -- PhpStorm has some integration but I'm not sure if these specific cases are covered: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-psalm.html / https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpstan.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we adopted is this:

```php
<?php
class AbstractBuiltClass {
    /**
      * @return static
      */
    public static function type(self $instance)
    // change return type to :static when #PHP72 support is dropped and remove explicit typecheck
    :self
    {
        if(!($instance instanceof static)){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}

class Hammer extends AbstractBuiltClass{
    function hammerMethod(){}
}

Hammer::type($factory->get(Hammer::class))->hammerMethod();
```

Contenders for a viable solution:

1. Psalm template annotations: https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/templated_annotations/ very promising but not widely supported yet
2. Variable docblock (see [Alex Howansky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66479135/1710180))

Answer (score 0):

Philosophical conversations about breaking the D in SOLID aside, if you want something like this to autocomplete the methods that are available *only* on `Hammer`:

```
(new AbstractFactory())->build1(Hammer::class)->
```

Then you have *already* committed to writing this block of code specifically for the `Hammer` class. And if you're going to do that, then you might as well do this:

```
$hammer = (new AbstractFactory())->build1(Hammer::class);
```

And if you do that, then you might as well do this:

```
/**
 * @var Hammer
 */
$hammer = (new AbstractFactory())->build1(Hammer::class);
```

And then your autocomplete on `$hammer->` should work.

Comment: While dogmatically correct, this comes with heavy practical implications for me (isn't there always something?). Namely, what I am doing right now is replacing some statically generated instances with factory generated ones through a large codebase; the said entities are so frequently used that, obviously, they appear in long catenas of fluent code. This makes for a pretty ugly refactoring, and transforms something that would take 1 second and no trainig (like writing `$factory->get(Instance::class)`) to something more complicated; so I am really hoping I can pull it out from my IDE...

Comment: Still doctrinarily speaking, my problem is most correctly addressed by using DI for the instances, but again, it would mean such a brutal refactoring that I'm just looking for the quck escape this time :)

Comment: Following a good night's sleep, I'm leaning towards using a construct like this:

```php
class AbstractBuiltObject {
    /** @return static */
    public static from(self $instance): self { // :static from 7.4+
        if(!($instance instanceof static)){
            throw new Exception('wrong');
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}

Hammer::from($factory->get('find me a hammer'))->hammerMethod();
```

Seems to work like a charm in terms of static analysis, doesn't break patterns too bad. Do you see any downsides to it?

Comment: Then use as `Hammer::from($factory->get(...))->hammerMethod()` this would allow preserving fluent code sequences and minimal refactoring overhead. I think it's also the maximum level of polymorphism PHP can provide at this point...

Comment: Another solution would be using templates https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/templated_annotations/ to model something like `Factory::get<Hammer>(): Hammer` but this doesn't seem fully supported by Storm yet